# Using group by but generate several columns

Tags: sql, group-by

I'd like to get something a little bit *strange*.

Let me start with what I *want*:

day                  Code0   Code1   ... ... CodeN

01/01/2016       20           23                  3

02/01/2016       16           18                  7

etc

Given that I have a table *Codes* this is what I have so far:

```
select [day], SUM(value) as Total, code into #tablaTemporal1
from Codes
group by [day], code
```

Which gives me:

day                  Total         Code

01/01/2016       20           Code0

01/01/2016       23           Code1

01/01/2016       3           CodeN

02/01/2016       16           Code0

02/01/2016       18           Code1

02/01/2016       7           CodeN

etc

It's important to say that the number of different codes N is *limitless*; and by limitless I mean that they might change.

Is there any way to instead of getting a row for each day and code I get a single row per day but giving me the total for each code in the columns?

Comment: this is exactly what `pivot` is for.

Comment: Dynamic pivoting is much cleaner and easier in the display layer (report, app, web page, etc.).  SQL is not designed for dynamic pivoting since it generally likes to have a fixed set of columns,

Answer (score 0):

For a *predefined* set of `Code` values you can use a query like this:

```
select [day], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 'Code0' THEN value END) as Code0, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 'Code1' THEN value END) as Code1, 
       ...
       SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 'CodeN' THEN value END) as CodeN
from Codes
group by [day]
```

Comment: It's not predefined :( I tried that as well when I thought they were limited but I saw today that there are some new ones so N should be considered limitless

Comment: Then you need a dinamic pivot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Answer (score 0):

dynamically put all the agregate columns into a variable @cols and the assumption I made is that your temp table is named #t. If you need a real table you'll have to change the inner query to something like

> SELECT name FROM YourDatabaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE
>   TABLE_NAME = N'yourTableName'

```
 DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ', ', '') + 'sum('+Name +') as ' + name
    FROM 
    (
        select name as name from tempdb.sys.columns 
        where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#t') and name!='day'
    )cols
```

then

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT day,' 
    + @cols +
    ' FROM #t GROUP BY day';
```

and voila, the @sql variable  has now  a dynamic sql to what you want:

> SELECT day,sum(code0) as code0, sum(code1) as code1, sum(code4) as
>   code4 FROM #t GROUP BY day

now execute it

```
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Please mark this as useful if it helped you. Thanks:)